# Express-validator Validate Owner document with midelware

Tags: mongodb, express, validation, mongoose, express-validator

I have an API with Nodejs and Mongo, and I want to validate with Express-validator module if the document is owned by Signin user or not.

I want to do that by Midelware, and getting a String for know what is the collection I need to query.

*programacionRouter.js*

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const { check } = require('express-validator');

router.get('/:id', [
    validarJWT,
    check('id', 'No es un ID válido').isMongoId(),
    // Here I want a custom MIDELWARE like -> isOwener('Users')
], obtenerProgramacion);
```

Where I put a comment I want a custom MIDELWARE like -> isOwener('Users'). If I pass Users query Users Mongodb table, and if i pass recipes I want to query Recipes table.

And here the controller:
*programacionController.js*

```
const { handleHttpError } = require('../helpers/handleError');
const { Programacion } = require('../models');

exports.obtenerProgramacion = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const { id } = req.params;

        // I want to do this as a Midelware -->
        // 1. Check if ID exist in this Collection
        // 2. Check if this collection is Owned by User logged
        const programacion = await Programacion.find({ semana: id, usuario: req.usuario._id });

        // No se encuentra la reunión o no pertenece al usuario
        if (programacion == '') {
            return res.json({ msg: 'No existe ninguna reunión con esa ID' });
        }

        res.json({
            msg: 'Programación cargada correctamente',
            programacion
        });

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        handleHttpError(res, 'ERROR_OBTENER_PROGRAMACION', 400);

    }

};
```

See comments in the code. I want to do two checks as a Midelware.
// 1. Check if ID exist in this Collection (function for all collections)
// 2. Check if this collection is Owned by User logged

Is this possible with express-validator?

**Added question**
Really I need to do a Midelware for this validation or it's the same if I only return my document by user._id? Like:

```
const query = { estado: true, usuario: req.usuario._id };
```

Comment: 2 days. Can anyone help me please? I'm stuck on my code now :(

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Could you please edit your question and place the model from your User and Owner collection?.